# How to open local files from a local WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to open files of various mime types (.doc, .xls, .pdf) from the local hard drive i.e. c:/ using a link in a local WordPress installation. I have tried a few variations of the following without any success at all:

```
<a href="file:///abc/hi.doc">file</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you mean files on your computer?

Comment: @charankumar yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using wordpress default Retrieve stylesheet directory URI

example:

```html
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img.png" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

Comment: Hi Manpreet, thanks for your response. I mean files on the local drive not in the WordPress install. I'll reword my question to make it clearer. Cheers.

Comment: can you try adding drive name as well <a href="file:///K:/hi.doc">file</a>.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, You may need to include local drive drive path also

```
<a href="file:///C:/hi.doc">file</a>
```

assuming hi.doc file is in root of "C" drive

Comment: This works in a standard HTML doc but not from within WordPress.